# How to enable Github Pages with Custom Domain

Tags: github

I've read through the Github help pages for setting up custom domains, but to no avail.

I have just pushed a new Jekyll project to github and am trying to point my domain name to it. I have the domain registered with a provider and in their zone editor I have added www.my-domain.com, type CNAME with record my-repo.github.io (my-repo same as my-domain). My reasoning for redirecting only www is because I want to keep all my services like email and such with my provider, so I've just configured a subdomain (wwww).

In github, the repository name is my-domain.github.io and the pages are being built from the master branch, though I have also added a gh-pages branch as well. The 'custom domain' in settings is set to 'www.my-domain.com'.

Normally, I'd wait for it to propagate if it weren't for this error. When viewing the settings page, I see this error in the github settings page.

```
Your site is having problems building: Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds/.
```

And emails that says ...

```
The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds/.

For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:

https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds

If you have any questions you can contact us by replying to this email.
```

I don't see anything specific about the error.

Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you're encountering a ["Generic Jekyll build failures"](https://help.github.com/articles/generic-jekyll-build-failures/). GitHub recommends that you [build your site locally](https://help.github.com/articles/generic-jekyll-build-failures/), which might help troubleshoot it... Otherwise, it's hard to tell what's going wrong, since you haven't really posted any references to your GitHub site... (BTW, none of this seems related to custom domains, it's really before custom domains ever get involved. Is my-domain.github.io working? My guess would be "no".)

Comment: When I go to my-domain.github.io, it changes to my-domain.com and shows a hithub 404 page. I can git pull my website and do a 'jekyll build' on my machine and it runs fine via loopback, if that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant about doing a local 'jekyll build'... Is it possible that you're using Jekyll plugins that are not supported by GitHub? See this page for more details: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/

Comment: The only plugin in my _config.yml file is jekyll-feed, which was part of the minima theme. My site is very basic at this point.

Comment: Any chance you could post the real name of your GitHub repository containing the GitHub pages? (Assuming it's public...) It's really hard to figure this one out in a vacuum...

Comment: Thanks, it now seems to be working and I have no idea why. What I did was remove the repo and push it again.